# Why getting list index out of range while selecting by string?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-lab

I've got this code so far to scrape OEM, OEM Number, Description, ANS-Number from this site and its giving me a list index out of range

```
pip install beautifulsoup4

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "https://www.advantagenationalsupply.com/oem-catalog/"

result = requests.get(url)

doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

print(doc.prettify())

ANS = doc.find_all(text="ANS-")

print(ANS)

parent = ANS[0].parent
```

I tried to run this and expected to get a `list` of items pertaining to ANS on the website. But instead I got "list index out of range"

Comment: `doc.find_all(text="ANS-")` is `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Main issue here is that value of [`string argument`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument) has to be a full match, else you have to go with [`regex`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) while using `find_all()`.

```
doc.find_all(string=re.compile("ANS-"))
```

---

Make it more simple and use [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to scrape tables, that is best practice and will cover most cases.

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html(url)[0].iloc[:,1:-1]
```

##### Output

|  | OEM | OEM Number | Description | ANS-Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bettcher | 100711 | Spacer | ANS-BW-0011 |
| 1 | Carruthers | 000878-12 | 1/4" Spacer | ANS-CRS-0001 |
| 2 | Carruthers | 000878-12-SS | 1/4" Spacer SS | ANS-CRS-0001SS |
| 3 | Carruthers | 000878-14 | 3/8" Spacer | ANS-CRS-0012 |
| 4 | Carruthers | 000878-15 | 1/2" Spacer | ANS-CRS-0016 |
| 5 | Carruthers | 000878-16 | 3/4" Spacer | ANS-CRS-0003 |

...

---

In alternative select your elements more specific with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
doc.select('tr:has(td:-soup-contains("ANS-"))')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.advantagenationalsupply.com/oem-catalog/"
doc = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

[dict(zip(doc.select_one('thead').stripped_strings, e.stripped_strings)) for e in doc.select('tr:has(td:-soup-contains("ANS-"))')]
```

##### Output

```
[{'OEM': 'Bettcher',
  'OEM Number': '100711',
  'Description': 'Spacer',
  'ANS-Number': 'ANS-BW-0011',
  'Quantity': 'Add to Quote'},
 {'OEM': 'Carruthers',
  'OEM Number': '000878-12',
  'Description': '1/4" Spacer',
  'ANS-Number': 'ANS-CRS-0001',
  'Quantity': 'Add to Quote'},
 {'OEM': 'Carruthers',
  'OEM Number': '000878-12-SS',
  'Description': '1/4" Spacer  SS',
  'ANS-Number': 'ANS-CRS-0001SS',
  'Quantity': 'Add to Quote'},...]
```